# Есть ли разница между этими проверками ? Ибо вторая работает как следует, а первая просто игнорируется

Tags: javascript

1. a <= item <= b
2. a <= item && item <= b

Comment: Все правильно. Почти ни в одном языке программирования двойные неравенства не работают и их надо писать через логическое И, как во втором примере.

Comment: @Talleyran python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Первое выражение синтаксически правильно, но делает не то, что кажется на первый взгляд. Могут быть случаи, когда оно покажется рабочим, но в большинстве случаев это будет иллюзией.

Операторы сравнения имеют одинаковый приоритет, но вычисляются слева направо. Поэтому, например, в таком выражении:

```js
1 <= 2 <= 1 // как ни странно, true
```

порядок действий под капотом такой:

1. 1 <= 2 — даёт true.
2. true <= 1 — true приводится к числу 1 и 1 <= 1 тоже даёт true.

Поэтому нужно пользоваться вторым выражением.

Answer (score 3):

Она не игнорируется.

```
let a = -6
-8 <= a <= -4
```

дает `false`, т. к.:

- `-8 <= a` -- `true`,
- a `true <= -4` -- false